# Rails plugin task deprecation warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, warnings, rake, deprecated

I'm having this warning in my project:

DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/shoulda/tasks, and vendor/plugins/svg_web/tasks are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead.

I read how to fix it, moving the tasks to lib/tasks. But I'm curious about the reason. Does anyone knows why is this? If I want to develop a plugin  now with a rake taks how should I do it?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore this, it is just a warning that the plugins rake tasks are not in what is now considered the correct folder. 
It is possible that there are later versions of the plugins that sort the problem.